# Guardar variable global dentro de una función

Tags: array, ios, swift

¿Cómo puedo guardar una variable de tipo array de una función en otra variable para acceder a ella de manera global?

Por ejemplo, he intentado algo como esto:

```
var arrayGlobal = [String]()
func ejemplo(){
  var array = [String]()
  array.append("valor 1")
  self.arrayGlobal = array
}
fun imprimir_items(){
  for item in arrayGlobal{
    print(item)
  }
}
```

y quisiera que me imprimiera el valor 1. ¿Cómo podría hacerse?

Comment: ¿Lo de `fun` en lugar de `func` es un fallo al copiar el código a la pregunta? ¿Recibes algún error en la consola?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya se cumple lo que tu quieres, solo es necesario llamar ambas funciones en el siguiente orden:

```
self.ejemplo() 
self.imprimir_items()
```